# How can I ban visitor automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like some advice on how could I ban a visitor, I created a board where you can post without having account and other user can report if you are abusing. After 50 report the post is deleted and the visitor should be ban (cannot post or comment anymore) with his IP address.

I took a look to the gem `rack-attack` but it doesn't seems to fit to my problem. If I understand well I have to add IP in the blocklist or allow2ban by myself and it's not what I'm looking for.

Also I was think about saving the Ip in a table like `user_ban` but I don't know how I could unban them automatically after few hours or days.
This is why I'm looking for advice or ideas.

Thank you

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want to ban a specific user, but you are not tracking users in any way?  Or are you tracking users somehow?

Comment: Yes, I know they can just change their IP and post again but I think for many people it's difficult or annoying to do

Comment: But are you tracking IP's at all?  I mean, I think you are going to need something to link a user to a banned account in some way, otherwise what are you banning/blocking?

Comment: I just check his IP when I need with `request.remote_ip`, for example if the user is creating a new article, in my controller `create` I would check if ihs IP is in my ban list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k. so based on what you said, I would recommend a before action in the application controller to just redirect out if the user's ip is in the banned list.  Since IP is the only thing you are tracking it is the only thing we have to work with, which, as you mentioned, is not 100%, but it seems like it is the best we can do.  In the code below `banned_ip_list` would include all your banned ips.  since you do not specifically say what you would like to do to the banned user I left that open for you inside the method to fill in.

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :check_if_user_is_banned

...

private 

  def check_if_user_is_banned
    if banned_ip_list.includes?(request.remote_ip)
      # what do you want to do here? Keep redirecting to a page and display a message?
    end
  end
```

Comment: So if I want for the visitor the possibility to see article but not create new one, when it will call the method `show` it will call `check_if_user_is_banned` and then if he is he will be redirected to the main page ? How can I make a difference with the action I want to allow the visitor to do or not ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Ok to do that you would move this into the controller that handles those methods(actions) and specify the methods it applies to like this `before_action :check_if_user_is_banned, only: [:show]` , Inside the brackets you would just place the methods in the controller to apply the before action to.  Again, you would move this out of the application controller and put it in the controller whose methods it applies to.

Comment: Thank you it work perfectly and look nice in the code. I appreciated your help !

Comment: glad it helped, happy coding